# Codeception generated functional test raising error 'use statement with non-compound name'

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, codeception

I'm trying to run codeception tests written by another dev at my organization. I'm on php 5.6 and this is a laravel 5 app with codeception 2.1. The specific error that I'm getting is
 
`The use statement with non-compound name 'FunctionalTester' has no effect`

Every codeception-generated functional test in our directory includes the line 

`use \FunctionalTester;`; i can suppress the error just by adding `as ft;` to the end of the line, but that's not the point.

in some other examples online i see the keyword `namespace` instead of `use` here.

as a final example, the command `php ./vendor/bin/codecept generate:cest functional foo` generates the following file, (which will raise that error)

```
use \FunctionalTester;

class fooCest
{
  public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
  {
  }blah blah blah
```

btw, php is not my main language. Even if this `use` with no namespace were redundant, i don't see the point of raising on it. OK! Thanks!

Comment: is there a question in that?

Comment: The error for using `use` with an object in the global namespace - a non-compound object.  The code causing it is generated automatically by codeception. It is only happening on my system as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what your question is because all there is here is statements. :)

Comment: I'm wondering why I am getting an error from code generated by the codeception framework when it doesn't seem to be an issue for others. I guess my question is about running tests without raising an exception on line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Codeception to 2.1.5, this issue is fixed already: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commit/892f85388c8dd2c57e120f9a3e225074a9ae175b

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
use \FunctionalTester;
```

The reason you're getting that warning is that while being in global namespace you're trying to import a class from a global namespace, which is not needed and hence has no effect.